# How to ascend the list in PHP by using variable?

Tags: php, sql

I am using a while loop to display some output. I have 3 divs and each of them has 3 list outputs. So, in total I have 9 outputs. Now I want to display 9 category name from the database in ascending order such that first 3 list will show first 3 category name, next 3 list will show next 3 category name and so on.. How I can do that using a variable? I don't want to use SQL Query. In this code I have used to variable just to show first 3 category name. On the next div, I want to show category name 4-6 sequentially... Can anyone please help? Here's my code :

```
<?php
    $res=select_all_category_name();
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h1 class="text-center">ALL CATEGORY LISTS</h1>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php
                        $count=0;
                        $max=2;
                        while($cat_info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) and($count<=$max)) {?>
                            <a href="products.php?category_id=<?php echo $cat_info['category_id'];?>"><li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $cat_info['category_name']; ?> <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                            <?php $count++;}?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li class="list-group-item">Test name <span class="badge">12</span></li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want the output such the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can "chunk" the results of your query into parts with array_chunk 
see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Then you can:

```
$groups = array_chunk($my_query_result);
foreach($groups as $group){
  echo '<div class="group">';
     foreach($group as $cat_info){
        echo '<ul>';
        echo $cat_info['category_name'];
        echo '</ul>';
     }
  echo '</div>'
}
```